# TypeScript 3.7 is now throwing error for all individual (invalid) props rather than grouping them like before

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript3.0, react-typescript

Case with **TypeScript 3.5.3**
[image]
link to playground - [TS 3.5.3 working](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2&ts=3.5.1#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BhXSGpGmAQTgF44AKAJS8AfHBoBXADZSKleZWr14wAIy84AHmbha7LuThG4KHgG9VAX0PGARuYBM1gPQjKz5wAEYdALTAAcxpoJDgAd2gAazo4QFByKloGOGAHDW0WPQ5OGyNTC2tjOHszJ3JXIA)

Case with **TypeScript 3.7.2**
[image]
link to playground - [TS 3.7.2 not working](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BhXSGpGmAQTgF44AKAJS8AfHBoBXADZSKVWgzjAAjLzgAeZuFrsu5OAbgoeAb2UBffYYBGpgEyWA9CMqPHAARh0AtMADmNNBIcAAmEEh04hDwAO7QANZwABZIREY0AJ4gQXCAMuRw8vTwwHZqmiw6HJxWBsZm5nBuGt4t3nCpOFBKkdQgwDR%20yanBgTE1cLYmDuTO5EA)

Comment: Isn't `@ts-ignore` supposed to only ignore the next line? http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BhXSGpGmAQTgF44AKAJS8AfHBoBXADZSKVWgzjAAjLzgAeZuFrsu5OAbgoeAb2UBffYYBGpgEyWA9CMrV68YHbWaWOjpysDR0cAARg6AFpgAHMaaCRAo1MLIMcNCIyIuCQoHCglOjhqEGAacmcgA

Comment: Yes @Cristy, but the problem here is ->

In ts@3.5.3 all the errors of any-and-all invalid props would come on the first line of the JSX syntax.

Now with ts@3.7.2, tsc is emitting errors individually for all of them on their own lines!

(So if 1 ts-ignore comment was doing the job of supressing, now multipler ts-ignores would be required)

Comment: Based on the docs, it looks like previously `@ts-ignore` was not working as expected, and now it seems fixed, correctly ignoring only the next line? And `@ts-ignore` shuld be avoided as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring whether or not `@ts-ignore` is good practice, you should be able to just stick it on the next line. [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?jsx=2&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=15&pc=3#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDG8BmUIjgcilQ3wG4AoctCAOwGd4BhXSGpGmAQTgF44AKAJS8AfHBoBXADZSKVWgzjAAjLzgAeZuFrsu5OAbgoeAb2UBffYYBGpgEyWA9CMrz68YHbWaWOjpysDR0cAARg6AFpgAHMaaCQ4AHdoAGs6OAALJCJxCES4QFByQKNTCzhgjQiqiLhsnCgldOoQYBpozOyEuMTi2xMHcmcgA)

Comment: Yes, its not a good practice, agreed.

But for some ts-code that you want it to just work (and not heavily maintain actively),
if adding one `@ts-ignore` worked till now, this change in ts3.7 makes us add a ton more `@ts-ignore`s

:/